# Formatting Active Directory Attributes value with PowerShell and RegEx where possible

Tags: regex, powershell, active-directory

I need to modify a PowerShell script to format automatically  Telephone and Mobile content into a specific pattern in my existing AD.

The source will be from all AD users with either Mobile or Telephone number exist:

```
function Get-CountryCode ($CountryCode)
{
    switch ($CountryCode)
    {
        "UK" { "+44" };
        "US" { "+1" };
        default { "" }
    }
}

$paramGetADUser = @{
    Filter     = "(Enabled -eq 'True')  -and (Mail -like '*') -and ( (Phone -like '*') -or (Mobile -like '*') )"
    Properties = 'EmailAddress', 'Mobilephone', 'OfficePhone', 'Country'
    SearchBase = 'OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=com'
    SearchScope = 'Subtree'
}


$ADUsers = Get-ADUser @paramGetADUser |
    Select-Object Name, EmailAddress, UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName, Mobilephone, OfficePhone, Country

ForEach ($ADuser in $ADUsers)
{
    If ($ADuser.MobilePhone)
    {
        Write-Host "Converting '$($ADuser.Name)' $($ADuser.Country) Mobile Phone number: '$($ADuser.MobilePhone)' ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        
        $paramSetADUserMobile = @{
            Identity    = $ADuser.SamAccountName
            MobilePhone = { $ADuser.MobilePhone -replace '0(\d)(\d{4})(\d{4})', "$(Get-CountryCode -CountryCode $ADuser.Country) $1 $2 $3" }
            ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
            Verbose     = $true
        }
        
        Set-ADUser @paramSetADUserMobile
        
        Write-Host "`t'$($ADuser.Name)' $($ADuser.Country) Mobile Phone number: '$($paramSetADUserMobile.MobilePhone)' ..." -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    
    If ($ADuser.OfficePhone)
    {
        Write-Host "Converting '$($ADuser.Name)' $($ADuser.Country) Office Phone number: '$($ADuser.OfficePhone)' ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        
        $paramSetADUserPhone = @{
            Identity    = $ADuser.SamAccountName
            OfficePhone = { $ADuser.OfficePhone -replace '0(\d)(\d{4})(\d{4})', "$(Get-CountryCode -CountryCode $ADuser.Country) $1 $2 $3" }
            ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
            Verbose     = $true
        }
        
        Set-ADUser @paramSetADUserPhone
        
        Write-Host "`t'$($ADuser.Name)' $($ADuser.Country) Office Phone number: '$($paramSetADUserPhone.OfficePhone)' ..." -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```

How can I make the below Function format Mobile phone number based on the country code:

From:

Telephone: 0xxxxxxxxx
Mobile: 0xxxxxxxxx

Into:

Telephone: +44 x xxxx xxxx
Mobile: +44 xxx xxx xxx

Source: https://www.visitnorthwest.com/essential/uk-telephone-numbers/

Updated as suggested by @Theo and @MarkAlex, however, the RegEx pattern is still not working.

Comment: Something like this: `Set-ADUser -Instance $yourUser -MobilePhone { $MobileNumber -replace '0(\d)(\d{4})(\d{4})', '+44 $1 $2 $3'}`? More on [`Set-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

Comment: Also, if this is one time task - save your self hustle with or in filter (and possible null as property value), and make to separate scripts for each phone to be converted.

Comment: Hi @markalex, no, it will be executed as part of the scheduled task once per hour. Because this is to standardize the telephone and mobile number as it is entered by many different people around the globe.

Comment: If you need to format telephone numbers from all around the globe, I guess you need a lookup table with all country names mapped to their country telephone-codes. See [this table](https://www.iban.com/dialing-codes) for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an issue with your code other than using a script block in the splatting hash tables and not escaping the regex replacement groups in the expandable strings. So essentially:

```bash
MobilePhone = { $ADuser.MobilePhone -replace '0(\d)(\d{4})(\d{4})', "$(Get-CountryCode -CountryCode $ADuser.Country) $1 $2 $3" }
```

Should be (changed regex too, to match the expected format):

```bash
MobilePhone = $ADuser.MobilePhone -replace '0(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})', "$(Get-CountryCode -CountryCode $ADuser.Country) `$1 `$2 `$3"
```

And:

```bash
OfficePhone = { $ADuser.OfficePhone -replace '0(\d)(\d{4})(\d{4})', "$(Get-CountryCode -CountryCode $ADuser.Country) $1 $2 $3" }
```

Should be:

```bash
OfficePhone = $ADuser.OfficePhone -replace '0(\d)(\d{4})(\d{4})', "$(Get-CountryCode -CountryCode $ADuser.Country) `$1 `$2 `$3"
```

Note that the backticks `` ` `` in `$1`, `$2` and `$3` are required in a expandable string `"..."`, otherwise, PowerShell will see them as variables and try to interpolate them in the string.

Comment: Wow, that is spot on, thanks @SantiagoSquarzon, yes it works beautifully now.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer glad it does :)

Comment: sorry for one more thing, how to modify the RegEx so that the mobile number will be split into +44 xxx xxx xxx ?

Comment: try with `-replace '0(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})', ....` the rest should be the same @SeniorSystemsEngineer

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at this a lot of ways and tried to get simplest results using combination of Regex and String Methods.  Try following :

```
$data = 'Telephone: 0xxxxxxxxx Mobile: 0xxxxxxxxx'
$pattern = 'Telephone:\s(?<tele>[^\s]+)\sMobile:\s(?<mobile>.*)'
$data -match $pattern
$newTele = $matches.tele
$newTele = '+44 '+ $newTele.Substring(1,1) + ' ' + $newTele.Substring(2,4) + ' ' + $newTele.Substring(6,4)
$newMobile = $matches.mobile
$newMobile = '+44 '+ $newMobile.Substring(1,1) + ' ' + $newMobile.Substring(2,4) + ' ' + $newMobile.Substring(6,4)
$output = 'Telephone: ' + $newTele + 'Mobile: ' + $newMobile
$output
```

Comment: Thank you @jdweng, the Source of the data is coming from the AD and the target is also going to the AD database, hence it is not the plain text operation.